# File not found for a library, but I have a newer version of it

Tags: c#, json, nuget

One of a libraries from `NuGet` depends on `Newtonsoft.Json version 7.0.1`. Here's what I have in `packages.config` of my desktop application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  ////...............
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

However, at runtime I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Why `7.0.0`? How can I solve this?

Nuget console:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1' already installed.
AzureDocumentDbBuddy already has a reference to 'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1'.
```

Comment: Does one of your *other* libraries depend on 7.0.0 (and only that version) perhaps?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I don't know.

Comment: Well that's what I'd try to figure out then. It's hard for us to help you do that knowing nothing about your application or the libraries it depends on.

Comment: @JonSkeet, how? there're plenty of dependencies in my project.

Comment: which .Net framework you are using?check if 7.0.1 is compatible or not

Comment: @shreesha: It will be - Json.NET is compatible with just about everything.

Comment: Well, I'd personally start off with an empty project, and add libraries to it one at a time, checking for the problem between each addition. There may well be a simpler approach, but I can't think of it off hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First uninstall the installed version:

```
Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Force
```

Then:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 7.0.0.0
```

Comment: what should it install?

Comment: Install-Package : Unable to find version '7.0.0' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.

Comment: Write: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version     "after this press Tab key" >> That would show the different versions for this package